# Menu open close button redirecting page to localhost page in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using template in this below link. In my project everything is working but now menu open close button corrupt. When I click menu close button in any page (forexample in `http://localhost:4200/Student`), then it is going `http://localhost:4200/#`. In normal, it must be work in below link. What can be reason of this?

[AvalonTemplate](http://www.primefaces.org/avalon-ng/#/)

Comment: Is there anything in your console?

Comment: No. There isn't any error in console. It redirecting to "http://localhost:4200/" blank page when click. I don't know how button working mechanism. So, I can't understand the problem. @Frayt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primeNg doing this open close operation in "onMenuButtonClick" method. And my problem was my code doesn't access onMenuButtonClick. And giving no console error. I provide accessing onMenuButtonClick then worked perfectly.